# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser for "Generated Source Code"

Tags: javascript, php, parsing, dom

From my understanding, there are two types of source code (`Generated Source code` VS `Source Code` per page (as describe in here [What is the difference between "Source" and "Generated Source"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163455/what-is-the-difference-between-source-and-generated-source)).

When I use the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), I notice that I could only get the `Source Code`.

How do I get the `Generated Source code`?

If it is not possible using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser , are there other ways using PHP to get the `Generated Source code`? (Optional)

If it is not possible using PHP to get the `Gebnerated Source code`, are there other ways using javascript to get it? (Optional)

**Updates 1**: With reference to the answer made by user `Shankar Damodaran`, I need to change my understanding that there are three types of source code as follows:

- Actual Source Code (e.g. PHP, ASPX. Usually applies to server-side scripts)
- Source Code (The source code before javascript and css is applied)
- Generated Source Code (the source code after javascript and css is applied)

Comment: As per your Update #1, are you after "Source Code" or "Generated Source Code"?

Answer (score 2):

You can't via PHP alone, you have to rely on either [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) or [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/), which are **headless browsers** that will render the page and return you the HTML structure you are looking for.

Comment: you can also find few more additional tools here http://stackoverflow.com/a/125256/1189040

Answer (score 0):

#### I think you misunderstood ..

***Source Code*** is Interpreted by the server 
***Generated Source Code*** is the one returned to the browser. (*Just the HTML stuff*)

What the HTML DOM parser does is that they play with the ***Generated Source Code*** and not with the actual ***Source Code*.**

#### To answer your questions...

> How do I get the Generated Source code?

You cannot get the **Actual Source Code** , unless by illegal means.

Comment: I think he is referring to the HTML source NOT the other also by generated source code he meant the page after running JavaScript etc.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is html response vs. DOM after the initialisation of the client side app.