# how to append values selected from autocomplete js

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

what i need

- i need to append values in html selected values from autocomplete

code

```
                   $('.autocomplete_ind').autocomplete({
                    lookup: industrys,
                    onSelect: function(suggestion) 
                    {
                        console.log(suggestion);

                        var thehtml = '<strong>industry name:</strong> ' + suggestion.name + ' selected<br> <strong>'+ suggestion.id+'</strong>';
                        $('#outputcontent').append(thehtml);
                        $(this ).attr( "value",  suggestion.value );
                   }
```

html element

```
 <input type="text"  autocomplete="off"  onChange="make_url();"
             id="industry_name"  class="biginput autocomplete_ind"  name="allindustry"  value="">
```

- i have tried with
- both of solution does not works .
- i like on select values from autocomplete values should be view view source also otherwise value remain empty .
- document.getElementsByName('allindustry')[0].placeholder=suggestion.value;
- $(this ).attr( "value",  suggestion.value ); it works like it append value attribute value="somevalue"
- but on view source value="" empty shown.
- any suggestion are most welcome

Comment: Anything you do with javascript will not be available when you do `view->source` of the page as the page was not loaded with those values that were generated with javascript. Take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163455/what-is-the-difference-between-source-and-generated-source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163455/what-is-the-difference-between-source-and-generated-source) for more info.

Comment: my req is to set values in html then get that values ; in autocomplete is there any another way

Comment: Sure, when do you want to set/get it?

Comment: set  :onchnage select automplete fires;

Comment: Something like this => [http://jsfiddle.net/hj4afLqq/](http://jsfiddle.net/hj4afLqq/) ? By the way, this uses autocomplete from `jQuery UI`